# Line breaks in PHP xmlwriter document

Tags: php, xml, php-5.4, php-5.6

I've got an XML feed I've created using `XMLWriter`. It works flawlessly in dev on a PHP 5.6 vagrant box. On the live server, running PHP 5.4 the feed fails to render with a message:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 3 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

If you view source it looks like this:

[image: source]

Somehow there are a couple lines being added into the XML document. The only difference between the servers is the PHP version (as far as I know).

Here's the first few lines of the XMLWriter code:

```
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openURI('php://output');
$xml->startDocument("1.0");
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->startElement("propertyList");
$xml->writeAttribute('date', date('Y-m-d-H:i:s'));
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: It's not from the code you've posted :) - And for the differences between the two servers compare the ini-settings, for example those about output buffering, prepend files etc.. And do you have the code under version control?

Comment: If the XML files you're generating aren't enormous you could always put the output into a string and trim() it before saving it to disc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quite a few changes from PHP 5.4 to 5.6... let alone changes in libxml...

First thing is obviously make sure there is no white space before opening `<?php` tag or after a closing tag if used.

It would help if you can determine when the new lines are introduced (assume they are new lines... have you used something like a hex viewer?).  Try writing to a temp location - want to determine if this occurs when serving the page or when xmlWriter is outputting.

**Things that come to mind...**

- Perhaps be explicit about what the `indetString` should be.  `$xml->setIndentString("    ");`
- Default encoding...?  Maybe try and get that set.  Would expect on opening xml tag... `encoding="UTF-8"`.  Use `startDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');` and probably should be sending header like: `header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8');`.  Is your `default_charset` UTF-8?
- What other differences between the two environments?  Things like`short_open_tag` etc.

  - `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED`?  Changed around 5.4?

**Workaround:**

- Try a call `ob_clean` before starting to write to the output stream.
- Use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).
- Upgrade the server, who wants to be on 5.4 these days :)

Comment: A tried EVERYTHING! But simple `ob_clean()` made a miracle! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the placement of Header('Content-type: text/xml');

Try this and make sure NOTHING comes before the header() call:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/xml');

...

?>
```

I guess this could help you!